# Docker swarm mode routing mesh not working

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

When I deploy a service on a swarm using:

`docker service create --replicas 1 --publish published=80,target=80 tutum/hello-world`

I can access the service only from the ip of the node running the container. If I scale the service to run on both nodes, I can access the service from both ips, but it will never run from a container on the other node. (as confirmed by the `tutum/hello-world` image).

The [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/services/#publish-a-services-ports-using-the-routing-mesh) suggests that load balancing should work when it says:

> Three tasks will run on up to three nodes. You don’t need to know which nodes are running the tasks; connecting to port 8080 on any of the 10 nodes will connect you to one of the three nginx tasks.

The swarm was created using `swarm init` and `swarm join`.

Using `docker network ls` the ingress swarm network is found on both nodes:

```
NETWORK ID          NAME                DRIVER              SCOPE
cv6hk9wce8bf        ingress             overlay             swarm
```

Edit:
Manager node runs linux, worker node runs OSX. Running `modinfo ip_vs` on the manager nodes returns:

```
filename:       /lib/modules/4.4.0-109-
generic/kernel/net/netfilter/ipvs/ip_vs.ko
license:        GPL
srcversion:     D856EAE372F4DAF27045C82
depends:        nf_conntrack,libcrc32c
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.4.0-109-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
parm:           conn_tab_bits:Set connections' hash size (int)
```

Running `modinfo ip_vs_rr` returns:

```
filename:       /lib/modules/4.4.0-109-
generic/kernel/net/netfilter/ipvs/ip_vs_rr.ko
license:        GPL
srcversion:     F21F7372F5E2331EF5F4F73
depends:        ip_vs
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.4.0-109-generic SMP mod_unload modversions
```

Edit 2:
I tried adding a linux worker to the swarm, and it worked as advertised, so the problem appears to be related to the OSX machine.

The problem is solved for me, however, I'll let the question stay for future reference.

Comment: What OS? Can you post the output of `modinfo ip_vs` and `modinfo ip_vs_rr` please?

Comment: @johnharris85 Manager node is linux, worker node is OSX. The modinfo command doesn't exist on the worker node. Output on the linux node is now in the question details.

Comment: Any firewalls between nodes?

Comment: @johnharris85 No, the firewalls are disabled on both nodes, and the nodes are connected over LAN.

Comment: Any error messages relating to ip_vs, iptables, ingress in your docker daemon logs?

Comment: And can you paste the exact commands you used to init and join the swarm? (redact secrets obviously) Also what version of Docker is this?

Comment: @johnharris85 Running grep on the logs on the manager yielded no results for any keywords. On the worker there was only a few instances of IPVS being [mentioned](https://pastebin.com/UE73yt1H), but no errors.

Comment: @johnharris85 The swarm was initialized with `docker swarm init`, and the worker joined using: `docker swarm join --token <join-token> <manager-ip>:2377`. The command was generated using `docker swarm join-token worker`

Answer (score 4):

Ensure that `7946/tcp`, `7946/udp`, and `4789/udp` are open and available to all nodes in the cluster BEFORE `docker swarm init`.

Not sure why, but if they are not open PRIOR to **creating to the swarm**, they will not properly load balance.

- https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/ingress/

Answer (score 1):

This happen to me, it was caused by a firewall issue. So I open the ports on every worker and manager.

```
sudo firewall-cmd --permanent --add-port=2377/tcp
sudo firewall-cmd --permanent --add-port=7946/tcp
sudo firewall-cmd --permanent --add-port=4789/udp
sudo firewall-cmd --reload
sudo reboot
```

Restart server if that doesn't work. Docker service may need to reload too.